# How do i display zip code options during checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I was recently working on shipping methods in woocommerce that allows customers to pay for a specific shipping fee based on their location. But, during checkout when the country (Nigeria) is selected, post/zip code field disappears. Went ahead to choose a different country and the post/zip code field appears.

please, I’ll like to display zip code options during checkout, how do I get this done?
I’m so confused.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The postcode field was hidden for Nigeria in 3.5, you can see the reasoning given here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/21055

> While the Nigeria Postal Service (http://nipost.gov.ng/) introduced
>   Postal Codes a few years ago, they aren't being used by hardly anyone.
>
> Nobody knows their postal codes as the implementation is very
>   convoluted and nothing was done to sensitize the public or encourage
>   their use. You won't find them on any addresses and they aren't
>   required for finding a building/location or for delivering parcels.

If this is incorrect, you should file [an issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues).

To change this behaviour on one site, though, you can use filter `woocommerce_get_country_locale`, like so:

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_get_country_locale',
    function( $locales ) {
        $locales['NG']['postcode']['hidden'] = false;

        return $locales;
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much..